# How to get Routing information and render elements conditionally using Xstate state machine?

Tags: angular, state-machine, xstate

I'm using Angular + Typescript.
I would like to learn `Xstate` and am using a simple example. I have three components `Header`, `Home` and `Summary`.

Header

```
<h1>This is the header</h1>
<button>Previous</button>
<button>Cancel</button>
```

Home with `'/'` directory

```
<h1>This is the homepage</h1>
```

Summary with `'/summary'` directory

```
<h2>This is the summary page</h2>
```

I would like to hide the `Previous` button in my Home component but display it in my Summary component, and display the `Cancel` button in my Summary component but hide it in my Home component. And for that I need to know the path I am right now. How can I do that in Xstate?
And then, how will I render the buttons conditionally?

I have learned how to write the states and transition from one to another, but i'm missing this part and how to put everything together.
Thank you

Comment: What do Previous and Cancel buttons do and how are they reflected in your state machine?

Comment: @FarzadYousefzadeh the button should do what the names suggest, go to Previous page and Cancel form submission